# Vector space of recursive sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I never faced this kind of vector space, so i'm a little insecure with how to solve this.

**Question**: Let $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ be non vanishing complex numbers. We consider the space of sequences defined inductively as follows: $$E\doteq\{(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}};\forall n\in\mathbb{N},u_{n+2}=au_{n+1}+bu_{n}\}.$$

(a) Show that $E$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space and determine its dimension.

(b) Let $r\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Give a necessary and sufficient condition on $r$ for the sequence $(r^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be an element of $E$.

(c) Deduces a basist for $E$.

Comment: To show it is a vector space you need to show that it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication and a few other axioms for a vector space (e.g., there exists an identity element, an inverse element, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $a$ and $b$ the values in each sequence $(u_n) \in E$ are determined by $u_0$ and $u_1$. So we can describe each term in each sequence as being a function of $n$, $u_0$ and $u_1$:

$(u_n) = (f(n, u_0, u_1))$

This *suggests* that $E$ could be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $2$.

A natural definition of addition on $E$ is then:

$(u_n) + (u_n') = (f(n,u_0,u_1))+(f(n,u_0',u_1')) = (f(n,u_0+u_0',u_1+u_1'))$

and a natural definition of multiplication is

$\lambda(u_n) = \lambda(f(n,u_0,u_1)) = (f(n, \lambda u_0, \lambda u_1))$

To prove that $E$ with these definitions of addition and multiplication actually is a vector space you need to show that it satisfies the axioms of a vector space.

Once you have proved that $E$ is indeed a vector space of dimension $2$ then one possible basis is $e_1=(f(n,1,0))$ and $e_2=(f(n,0,1))$. Then for any $u_0, u_1$ you have

$(f(n,u_0,u_1)) = (f(n,u_0,0)) + (f(n,0,u_1)) = u_0e_1 + u_1e_2$

Part (b) of the question suggests an alternative basis for $E$. If $(u_n=r^n)$ is a member of $E$ then $r^{n+2} = ar^{n+1} + br^n$. Since $r \ne 0$ we can divide through by $r^n$ to get $r^2 = ar + b$. This quadratic equation has roots $r_1$ and $r_2$. If the roots are distinct i.e. $r_1 \ne r_2$ then another possible basis is $e_1=(r_1^n)$ and $e_2=(r_2^n)$.